# How to use custom parents in Android style.xml file?

Tags: android, css, xml

In my android app I make use of styles in the style.xml. I have this one

```
<style name="EditText" parent="@android:style/Widget.EditText">
    <item name="android:gravity">center</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">#000000</item>
    <item name="android:layout_width">fill_parent</item> 
    <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item> 
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/bg_edit_text</item>
</style>
```

But now I have another one, and I want the parent to be the code above. If I try

```
parent="@android:style/EditText"
```

it says it can't be found. Does anyone know how it's done?

Thanks

Comment: why is this tagged css?

Comment: Not entirely sure, but I don't think that this style is in the android namespace, and that's the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your EditText style is a custom style so putting `@android:style/` will not work. Based on the android documentation on style inheritance, you can directly specify the name

```
parent="EditText"
```

or specify it in the `name` attribute without using the `parent` attribute

```
name="EditText.YourNewStyleName
```

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html#Inheritance